# Solving a Heat Equation

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic, heat-equation

I'm new to Mathematica and am a little lost as to how to code this heat equation:

u(0, *t*) = 0, u(L, *t*)=0, t>0

u(x, 0)= 1, 0<x<L/2
= 0, L/2<x<L

How would I go about solving this?

Answer (score 2):

12.2 on windows.

[image]

```
ClearAll[x, t];
pde = D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
ic = u[x, 0] == Piecewise[{{1, 0 < x < L/2}, {0, L/2 < x < L}}];
bc = {u[0, t] == 0, u[L, t] == 0}
sol = DSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, u[x, t], {x, t}, Assumptions -> L > 0]
```

[image]

```
sol0 = Activate[u[x, t] /. First@sol /. Infinity -> 15 /. L -> 10];
Manipulate[
 Quiet[Plot[sol0 /. t -> t0, {x, 0, 10}, 
   PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-.2, 1.2}}]],
 {{t0, 0, "time"}, 0, 25, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {t0}
 ]
```

For comparison, Here is Maple's solution

```
restart;
pde := diff(u(x,t),t) = diff(u(x,t),x$2);
ic := u(x, 0) = piecewise(0<x and x<L/2,1, L/2<x and x<L,0) ;
bc := u(0,t) = 0, u(L, t) = 0;
sol := pdsolve([pde, ic, bc], u(x,t)) assuming L>0
```

[image]